# Open Failed: EACCES(Pemission Denied) in Android 11

Tags: java, android

While trying to upload a file from internal storage am getting an Exception for open failed: `EACCES Denied`.
I have added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

```java
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
        READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION},1);
    requestPermission();
    //startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}")));
    return;
}
```

Comment: There is no code that tries to upload something or that tries to open something. And requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" works only for an Android 10 device. You can remove all the code you posted as we do believe that you request permissions at runtime. Post relevant code instead. And if you really use (Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION you should have told so.

Comment: how to  write this sir..  (Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION

Answer (score 1):

In Android 10 and 11, you've to use Scoped Storage to access files. But, if you set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` to `true`, then you can work with the previous methods of accessing storage in Android 10.

For Android 11, you've to set `targetSDKVersion` as `29`, not `30` to make `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` work as mentioned in the below image, Reference - [Storage updates in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage).
[image]

So, in your build.gradle (app), set `targetSdkVersion 29` or go with [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).

Comment: `or go with Scoped Storage.` Or directly write your image files in public directories like DCIM and Pictures. And you documents in the Documents folder.